# How to get status of Nginx HttpCacheModule?

Tags: caching, nginx, memcached

I cache on server by using HttpCacheModule of nginx.
I couldn't find how to get status of that.

For example, in memcached, we can get status like this.
http://www.mabishu.com/blog/2010/06/01/3-ways-of-get-memcached-status/

I'd like to same things on HttpCacheModule.
Especially, I'd like to check cache-miss.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got an answer myself. Just logging and collecting logs.

I wrote a post how to do that, thanks.

http://bekkou68.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/06/26/220131